# how to set the npm dependencies correctly?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-library

I want to contribute my Angular module to npm, and I did it. But I still confused about how to set the npm dependency correctly.

That Angular module dependence on `@angular/cdk @angular/material @angular/core he`. I notice angular-cli has automatically set the `@angular/core @angular/common` in `peerDependencies` property. I thought `@angular/cdk` etc are same as `@angular/core`, so I add the `@angular/cdk @angular/material @angular/core` in the `peerDependencies` too. But angular-cli warn me 'Cannot find module @angular/material' when I created a new project and lead this module into the project. Finally, I fix the problem by adding `@angular/cdk @angular/material @angular/core he` in `dependencies` property. But I am still confused about why it should be add to `dependencies` rather than `peerDependencies`. Further more, should I add it into `dependencies` or just tip it in the README.md that let other developer lead the dependencies to the project by themself.

[Project Github Address](https://github.com/Eriice/pretty-code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend googling the difference between dependencies and peer-dependencies for more detail but the gist of it is that peer dependencies are those that you expect a consumer of your library to have to install separate from your package but that are necessary for your package to run.

In general, it is best practice to define dependencies as peer dependencies when possible and for you it totally makes sense to. Why, you may ask? Well, if you define a version of the angular material cdk as a dependency and the consumer already has the angular material cdk installed in their project you will now have two versions of the same library that potentially conflict with each other.

In contrast, when you define a peer dependency, you're saying "hey, this library won't work unless you have material cdk installed, and I'll use whatever version that is". This is much better because they don't have to install it twice or worry about the different versions clashing.

All of what you listed should be in `peerDependencies` only thing I'd put in dependencies are things that are core to your library that you don't expect consumer developers to already have installed in their project. Since they are using what appears to be a plugin for a material project then it makes sense to do that. Although now that I visited your repo I don't see any mention of material UI. YOu do want to be very explicit in the peer dependencies needed by your library.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Cause it was my first time to contribute my code, I hope the project can be formal. I follow your advice, then add the dependencies to the `peer dependencies` and write a README.md to remind the consumer developers to installed those dependency package.